# RStudio knit to PDF: my images take the half of the page

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

i'm writing some codes in R in purpose to knit a PDF.
Here is the result when i put my graphs:

[image: my boxplots on my page]

I would like that my graphs take the whole page

here is the code i used:

```
b2=ggplot(tab,aes(group=price_range,y=ram,fill=price_range))+ geom_boxplot()

b3=ggplot(tab,aes(group=price_range,y=clock_speed,fill=price_range))+ geom_boxplot()


grid.arrange(b1,b2,b3)
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set fig.height and fig.width to suit your preferences, but a reasonable starting point could be to add the following to the top of the chunk where you make your visualizations.

```
{r, echo = FALSE, fig.height = 28, fig.width = 20}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know how to increase the size of the texts ? (title, axes)

Comment: Please see the box at the top that says this question already has answers here. In future it is best to search for answers to your question as typically these problems will have been addressed by the community previously.